# Physical meaning of different slip boundary conditions

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, navier-stokes

I am struggling to understand different slip boundary conditions. I have found, that there are Navier slip, dynamic slip, perfect slip and no-slip conditions (others may exist, but they are not relevant for me). I know, that no-slip means, that the fluid is sticking to the boundary. Perfect slip means, that the fluid is not sticking, it behaves like boundary does not exists. But I have no idea what other slip conditions means. Is there any physical motivation and/or intution?

Comment: Perfect slip means that the shear stress at the boundary is zero.  No-slip means that the fluid velocity at the boundary is zero.  The others, I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @vejvodma Have to think about the details, but perhaps, an analogy might help : For a simple mechanics problem (say, a block on a surface), we may think of several situations. If the surface is smooth there is no frictional force (shear stress at boundary = 0, velocity purely dictated by the forces acting on the block). If the Force on the block is less than the limit set of the static friction, we have frictional force (shear stress at bdy) is whatever it needs to be to prevent motion, and velocity = 0

Comment: @vejvodma If we carry this analogy further, we can see that the intermediate slip conditions are analogous to models of *dynamic friction*. I think the analogy with various kinds of drag in mechanics problems $\dot{v} = -\alpha v^{\beta}$ ,  may be fruitful. What that would mean in terms of setting a boundary condition on the flow velocity is something that isn't clear to me at the moment.